# Passing string to RegularExpressionValidator.ValidationExpression property

Tags: c#, asp.net, regex, webforms

I have the following regular expression:

`string RegexEmail = "^\\b[\\w\\.-]+@[\\w-\\.]+\\.(com|net|org|edu|mil)\\b$";`

The RegularExpressionValidator equivalent is as follows:

`<asp:RegularExpressionValidator ValidationExpression="^\b[\w\.\-]+@[\w\-\.]+\.(com|net|org|edu|mil)\b$" runat="server" />`

Aside from the differences in the escape sequence, is there a way to achieve passing a string variable to the ValidationExpression property? I've already tried with the RegexEmail variable but it treats the unquoted value it as a literal string such that...

`<asp:RegularExpressionValidator ValidationExpression=RegexEmail runat="server" />`

is rendered as:

`emailRegexVal.validationexpression = "RegexEmail"`

This is just for code readability purposes. Not sure what I'm missing if this is in fact possible.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

In the page markup:
`<asp:RegularExpressionValidator ID="validator" runat="server" />`

In the background code:
`validator.ValidationExpression = RegexEmail;`